# logstash - agent-Cannot create pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I get this error when trying to start logstash for the first time.

[logstash.agent           ] Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Expected one of #, \", ', -, [, { at line 3, column 17 (byte 34) after input{\n    file{\n        path => "}

I can't find any help online on why this is giving me this error.

this is my code:

```
input{
    file{
        path => /Users/my-computer/Desktop/data/CIM10FR.csv
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter{
    csv{
      separator => ","
      columns => [code, term]
      }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "CIM10FR"
        document_type => "hospitalcodesCIM10FR"
    }
    stdout{}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate path with double quotes, like below.

```
input{
    file{
        path => "/Users/my-computer/Desktop/data/CIM10FR.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter{
    csv{
      separator => ","
      columns => [code, term]
      }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "CIM10FR"
        document_type => "hospitalcodesCIM10FR"
    }
    stdout{}
}
```